# How can I use a Gamma Random Variable to Aproach the Expected value of a exponential random variable function?

Tags: random

I´m working on trying to approach the value of $E\left[ \dfrac{e^x}{x+1} \right]$. Where $x$ is an exponential random variable. All that data I have to work with is a gamma random variable with parameters $3/2$ and $1$. I also know that $x$ has mean $1$.

I think that I could get some relations by knowing that if I sum k exponential random variables I would get a gamma random variable. But I´m a bit confused on how I could apply this to the computation of the Expected Value. Can anyone suggest any valid process to compute the above value using the fact that I know the Gamma Random Variable??

EDIT:

POSSIBLE ANSWER:
I have received several comments about the divergence of the integral, however I think I can use this estimator to approach the value:

[image]

Where $T$ is the expected value of the gamma random variable and $Si$ the i-th value generated by the gamma distribution

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether you mean  $E\left[ \dfrac{e^x}{x+1} \right]$ or $E\left[ \dfrac{e^x}{x} + 1\right]$.  But neither of these exists (the improper integrals diverge).  Your gamma random variable is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: I´ve edited the question to correct the expression. Thanks for your answer, I don´t think the expected value does not exist for both since you can approximate it with simulation or other methods. My question is about how  can  I use this Gamma 'black box' to approximate the expression, even though they diverge. Thanks for your help

Comment: No!!!  You can **not** use simulation or any other method to "approximate" something that does not exist.

Comment: I think it does exist, since x is an exponential random variable with mean 1. But maybe I´m not being able to see something that you do.

Comment: The density for an exponential random variable of mean $1$ is $\exp(-t)$.  So 
$$ E\left[\dfrac{e^x}{x+1}\right] = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{e^t}{t+1} e^{-t}\; dt = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{dt}{t+1} = \infty$$

Comment: Now, the divergence is rather slow, so in a simulation it may not be very easy to see that it diverges, but nevertheless it really does diverge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So then it is possible to simulate it using the gamma variable? If that´s true what´s the best way to proceed?

Comment: You've **repeatedly** been told that the expectation is infinite, and despite this, you somehow continue to insist on "simulating" something.  You refused to believe you are wrong and had to have it **proven** to you.  I don't think any further assistance on your questions is justified because you have demonstrated incredibly obstinate behavior.

Comment: Hello I´m not being obstinate. I do understand what Robert said, but there must be another way around then. I´m reading a simulation book and got interested by this particular exercise I don´t think a simulation book has exercises with no solutions.

Comment: This would not be the first time a textbook exercise had a mistake.  Maybe try writing to the author?

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I´m sorry if I was obstinate, I was just trying to get an appropriate answer. Thanks for your time and knowledge